# Multiple SQL Strings in one PreparedStatement

Tags: sql, postgresql, prepared-statement

I've read on some other issues here, that it is not possible to use multiple different sql queries in one prepared statement.

```
String name = "XYZ";
int orderId = 10;
int imageId = 5;
String statement = "UPDATE T_order SET name = ? WHERE orderId =  ?; UPDATE T_Order_Relations SET imageId = ? WHERE T_Order_Relations.orderId = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(statement)
ps.setString(1, name);
ps.setInt(2,orderId);
ps.setInt(3,imageId);
ps.setInt(4,orderId);
```

I had assumed, that this would lead to an exception from dbms or anything else, but actually i can execute this statement without any problems. Also the changes are done in db. So is it may be possible to use queries like this ? 
Another question would be, are those both query executed like a single transaction (auto commit mode) ?
As DBMS im using PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: If there was a problem in one of the two `UPDATE` statements, could you identify which one failed?  Also, even if it is possible (which could be considered bad practice) wouldn't a stored procedure be better?

Comment: You're right with the identification. Didnt thought about that.. with stored procedures im not that familiar, but i will have a look on them